# Installing last release vs installing old ones and upgrading?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation, upgrade

Do I get the same result if I install an older archlinux version, say 2017.11 and upgrade it instead of downloading the latest version and installing that? Is in too much pain?

Comment: What reason do you have to not install the latest release, if this is what you want to run in the end?

Answer (score 3):

There are no "versions" of Arch Linux, other than the labels on the installation media. Once you boot into that image, for example with the kernel from 2017.11, when you install to your target machine, you will be downloading the current versions of all software on the mirrors.

There are reasons why you should prefer recent installation images, however: they will have more recent kernels which will provide better support for hardware, and as with any open source project, there are incremental improvements made in [the archiso project](https://git.archlinux.org/archiso.git/) between each monthly release.

Ulitmately, though, you will be downloading and installing the latest stable release of all packages to your target machine.

Obviously, you would not be advised to attempt an install from a particularly old image, as subsequent upgrades to pacman, pacstrap and other core utilities that support the installation will likely cause issues that would make this unnecessarily complex.